# Принцип создания dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день. Изучаю laravel, пробую сделать простой дашборд, у которого есть несколько страничек с таблицами и графиками. Как бы ничего сложного нету в том чтобы перейти на страничку и получить данные в нее. Но есть несколько вопросов.

1. Как правильно сделать динамический обновляемую таблицу? Например добавил я данные, они тут же в базе появились и на странице. Логично, что можно использовать ajax, но говорят, что это не лучшее решение и строить все запросы на ajax'ах не правильно и не модно. Хотя вроде это частая практика, когда вешают на кнопку обычный ajax, который возвращает данные и данные просто выводятся. Что думаете вы?
2. Помимо меня, изменить данные могут и другие пользователи, но я их увижу только если обновлю страницу. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы как-только данные изменились, у всех на странице динамический обновлялась таблица?

В какую сторону нужно копать? Спасибо.

Comment: пологаю можно это реализовать веб-сокетами. Но вам лучше разделить ваш вопрос на несколько

Comment: Если не читать второй вопрос, то на кнопку конечно просто вешать ajax. Если читать второй - то вебсокеты. А если почитать сначала, где "простой дашборд" то опять ajax)